# Thread Pool and Connection Pool , need help to understand how they work Java

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, threadpool, connection-pooling

So basically i am intern in a big company . I have to do a small java program(javaFX) that takes a csv list and updates our databases (3 Servers 6 Databases) . The file has over 700.000 entries and our server can support 50 connections . So my limit on the connections pool is 50 and i should work with not more than 200 threads . Thats the info i got from the lead programmer.

I started my project , made my object and made an observable list out of the csv file (lets say it has only Id and price in it , other fields are irrelevant anyway ). Where i am stack is  thread pools and connections pools. How can i work with both? In my newbie head i was thinking i will make a loop that makes 200 threads that execute the statements but then i have to use 50 connections so i should make 50 threads that open 50 connections from the pool and execute the updates ? If anyone has an example for me to understand how  threads with mysql connections work, i would be very greatfull as my head is gonna explode.

Comment: Each thread should use one connection.  So if the limit on the number of connections is 50, that means you cannot use more than 50 threads ... to talk to the database.  Note that it is NOT SAFE to try and share a JDBC Connection object between multiple threads.  JDBC objects (`Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, etc) are (typically) not thread-safe.

Comment: It is also unclear that it would be a good idea to try to run lots of parallel threads.  A better alternative may be to combine multiple updates into a single UPDATE statement *or* use batches.  (I'm a bit surprised that the lead programmer is advising you to go "all in" on parallelization ...)

Comment: “Takes a csv list” is this in memory or on disk?

Comment: Are you using a single input file to update three different databases?

Comment: Yes its a single file to  update 6 databases in 3 different servers .

Comment: CSV file is downloaded in the disk and mad into an object and then from that object i need to update those databases, with more than 700.000 entries.

Comment: Is the file in-premises? Are you updating existing records or inserting new ones? Having to download, write to disk to read from disk again seems one step too many if you have enough memory

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the need to go for multithreading for reading CSV file (IO) and loading the data to database. You can achive this without it. 
In Spring (Assuming JavaFX Supports Spring) You can read the data in Chunks as bytestream and load the data into database in batches (Say for example every 5000 rows). Below is an example snippet.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

//import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
//import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.billing.portal.notification.entities.Notification;

public interface NotifyRepo extends CrudRepository<Notification, Integer> {

}
```

**Implementation code below**

```
@Autowired
NotifyRepo notify;

int total=notifyRecords.size();
System.out.println("Total records are  "+total);
int limit=5000;
int start=0;
int rem=0;
boolean check=true;
if(total>5000) {
    rem = total-limit;
    while(check) {
            System.out.println("Start ::: "+start
                    +" limit ::: "+limit
                    +" rem ::: "+rem
                     );
            notifyRecords1 = notifyRecords.subList(start,limit);
            System.out.println("********************* Batch Insert Started from "+start+" to "+limit +"************************");
            notify.saveAll(notifyRecords1);
            System.out.println("Batch Insert Completed");
            if(limit==total) {
                break;
            }
            start=limit;
            rem=rem-5000;
            limit+=5000;    
            if(rem<=0) {
                limit=total;
            }

        }

    Batchload load = new Batchload();
    loadRepo.save(load);                    

    }else {

        System.out.println("Batch insert started, total less than "+limit);
        notify.saveAll(notifyRecords);
}
```

Comment: He didn't make it clear to me , so my guess is that he wants the program to update 6 databases in 3 different servers as fast as it can . So spread the threads between the 3 servers and 6 databases. I am trying to do it with Batches as you suggested . Every 5000 rows will do an an execute.

Comment: _He didn't make it clear to me , so my guess is_ the thing to learn as intern is to ask, ask, ask, ask your lead (and fellow workers) and the thing to unlearn is guessing :)